# Eps file looks funny in compiled pdf

Tags: errors, compiling, eps

I'm trying to include an eps file in my tex file. The tex file compiles fine, but the image in the pdf is only a small part of the actual image. The strange thing is that there are other eps files that compile perfectly well - it's just this image. The bad image was built entirely in Matlab, while the other ones were made partly in Matlab and completed in InkScape.

Any help or suggestions? I tried searching for this problem but don't see it. Thanks!

edit3: Including the link to the eps file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mol7oz0ksmry791/test_fig.eps?dl=0)

edit2: The error is exactly reproduced when I convert the eps file to pdf with 'epstopdf'.

edit: Here's the code that reproduces the error.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{test_fig.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here's the image before compiling. Note the middle row.
[image: pre-compiling]

Here's the image after including it in texmaker. You can see that the middle row is messed up.
[image]

Comment: Does it look like cropped? If yes, the bounding box stored in the file might differ from the actual file dimensions.

Comment: Without seeing the code and the `eps` files it might not be easy to help.

Comment: Try to convert the eps with an external tool like imagemagick or epstopdf and include the pdf in your document.

Comment: Can we download that EPS from somewhere?

Comment: epstopdf exactly reproduces the error. What's a good way to get the EPS to you? Dropbox link..?

Comment: `epstopdf` is used by latex as well. So this was kinda expected. A dropbox link will be fine. Please add it to the question, it gets more attention this way.

Comment: Do you have imagemagick (or something similar) installed? The pdf looks just fine using `convert test_fig.eps conradStevenFunnyEps.pdf`

Comment: I have imagemagick, but I need a vector format. Can imagemagick export a vector image? Are there other programs that can?

Comment: Open a cli and type in the above, you get a pdf (a vector graphics format).

Comment: Did you manage to get a good pdf?